# Android Random make a negative result, how to fix it?

Tags: android, random

I'm trying to make a random between 1 and 12. But the result is already negative and it make me the app stop.

This is my codes :

```
public class PlacementPerso extends AireDeJeu{
private boolean trou1, trou2, trou3, trou4, trou5, trou6, trou7, trou8, trou9, trou10, trou11, trou12;

private Random r = new Random();
private int random, baseMax, baseMin;

public void PlacementPerso(){
    trou1 = true; trou2 = true; trou3 = true; trou4 = true; trou5 = true; trou6 = true; trou7 = true; trou8 = true; trou9 = true; trou10 = true; trou11 = true; trou12 = true;
    random = 1; baseMax = 1; baseMin = 12;

}

public void aPlacer(Perso pPerso){
    final int ressource = pPerso.getRessource();


//This is the crash line
    random = r.nextInt((baseMax - baseMin) + 1) + baseMin;
/**
*
* AND MORE ....
*
*/
```

And the caller :

```
public class GenerateurPartie extends GenerateurPerso{

private int mNiveau;
public static int mAvancement = 0;
private int mDelai;
private Thread mThread;
private Perso mPerso;

private final HandlerDelai handlerDelai = new HandlerDelai();

protected static PlacementPerso mPlacementPerso = new PlacementPerso();

public GenerateurPartie(int pNiveau) {
    this.mNiveau = pNiveau;
    this.mDelai = 2500;

    mPlacementPerso.PlacementPerso();
   mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           try {
           int i = 0;
               while (mAvancement < 100) {

                   i += 1;

                   if (mAvancement >= 80)
                       mDelai = mDelai / 2;

                       Thread.sleep(mDelai);

                   handlerDelai.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                           mPerso = GenerateurPerso(mNiveau, mAvancement);

                           mPlacementPerso.aPlacer(mPerso);
                       }
                   }, mDelai);
               }
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
   }});
    mThread.start();


    }
}
```

I've already read some threads on stackOverFlow and tryed what they suggest to do but nothing resolve my problem.
I tryed to leave "random = 1;" in my class "PlacementPerso", but the way is already the same.

This is my log:

```
10-07 10:42:17.885 490-490/com.dunomade.ecraseurdetaupe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.dunomade.ecraseurdetaupe, PID: 490
                                                                      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: -10
                                                                          at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:182)
                                                                          at com.dunomade.ecraseurdetaupe.PlacementPerso.aPlacer(PlacementPerso.java:27)
                                                                          at com.dunomade.ecraseurdetaupe.GenerateurPartie$1$1.run(GenerateurPartie.java:56)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Maybe someone know how to resolve it. I don't understand why my result is already <=0.
Thank's advance =)

Comment: It seems you have flipped max and min values? max is 1 and min is 12.

Comment: Thank's a lot !!!! It was the problem =) I was blinded...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @cherry-wave said "you flipped max and min values". In future it is good practice to handle that error by thorwing exceptions or if You don't know which value is wchich You can also do something like this:

```
        //your values in class
        int baseMax = 1;
        int baseMin = 12;

        //when calling method to do math, first find the right min and max value
        int fixedMax = Math.max(baseMax, baseMin);
        int fixedMin = Math.min(baseMax, baseMin);

        //your further coce
        Random r = new Random();
        int random = r.nextInt((fixedMax - fixedMin) + 1) + fixedMin;
```

Or handle Your operation by exception i.e.:

```
        //checking if all is OK, because it MUST BE OK
        if (baseMax < baseMin) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("hey first value is smaller than second");
        }
        random = r.nextInt((baseMax - baseMin) + 1) + baseMin;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you've mistaken the place of baseMin and baseMax. We should have baseMax>baseMin. By swapping them your problem will be solved.
That is baseMax = 12, baseMin = 1;